# React-native 0.63 version performance issue in Android Devices

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I have recently upgraded my react-native project from 0.59 version to 0.63.1(latest) version. I have disabled hermes engine and configure everything as documented. My app is working fine on iOS but in android my app is performing slow. every UI event such as touch, navigation take 2s-3s delay on release build than before and lagging. Is there anyone who has faced same kind of issue? How you have solved this?

react-native: 0.63.1
react: 16.3
react-navigation: v5
Node.js: 12.3.1

Comment: Too many console.logs may produce this problem. 

You can take a look on this - https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance

Comment: I have already commented all console.log but although my total app is gonna slow

Comment: Have you found the reason for this?

It is also discussed in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26870

Comment: @Yossi i tried but didn't find any reason . I saw the Github link also but didn't get any solution so i make a fresh project and then move my code and dependency to the new project.

Comment: Thanks. And the new project's performance is good? is it using 0.63.3?

Comment: no..it is using 0.61.2

Comment: right now it is a very huge issue we had upgraded our app from 0.59.6 to 0.63.3 and now our Android app is very very very slow! we have made lot of changes recent in our code base interesting thing we had found in emulator app is running very fast but when we generate its apk app is very slow so seems like it is issue with production release

Comment: Any update on this?